# How to obtain response to be used on hooks

Tags: karate

I am trying to make a simplified version of test report where I am generating a single HTML file report containing only assertion and error response message when there is any (attempting to not publish all the logs and steps).

I understand that we have hooks in karate. However I have looked for karate objects in the github but unable to found any objects where I can extract the response from (to be passed to the js function called on hook)

What I am doing right now is this:

**Config**:

```
//karate-config.js
karate.configure('afterScenario', karate.call('classpath:hooks.js'));
```

**Hook**:

```
//hooks.js
//Looking on how to extract the response and log it here
function(){
    var info = karate.tags; 
    karate.log('Tags', info);
  }
```

Am I missing anything on the karate objects? Or this should be achieved in another way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var response = karate.get('response');
```

EDIT better example:

```
Background:
* configure afterScenario = function(){ karate.log('***', karate.get("response.headers['X-Karate']")) }

Scenario:
Given url 'http://httpbin.org'
And path 'headers'
And header X-Karate = 'test'
When method get
# this will fail
Then status 400
```

I have tried with both `karate.get('response')` and `response` directly, and both work. If you use `karate.call()` pass the `response` as a parameter.

Comment: Hi Peter.

It is returning `null` value

Comment: @Raymond see my edit. if you still have a problem, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I spotted an unusual behavior, even though I already put the `hooks.js` file as `afterScenario` or even `afterFeature` on `karate-config.js`, it is printing the log before the response is actually obtained.

Comment: @Raymond may be a bug - so see the link above ^

Comment: Thanks Peter! Will submit it

Comment: @Raymond hint - I think you just need `read('classpath:hooks.js')` you are confused between `call` and `read`.

Comment: OMG my bad. Thanks so much as always Peter!

Comment: @Raymond my bad as well, I did not spot it sooner